# SQL syntax error in WHERE CONTAIN query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I've got full-text indexing/search setup and I'm trying to pull any row where the 'LotteryChoices' column contains any of the query parameters. I keep getting an "Incorrect syntax near 'OR' " error. I've read through a bunch similar threads but they seem to have conflicting answers on the correct syntax for a WHERE CONTAINS query. Below is the query. Thanks in advance for any help, my SQL Fu is weak.

```
SELECT * FROM Lotto WHERE CONTAINS (LotteryChoices, 'Markley' OR 'Lindley' OR 'Tagert' OR 'Green' OR 'Goodwin' OR 'Wilson' OR 'Greene' OR 'Barnard' OR 'Opa' OR 'Taylor'
```

Comment: I'm surprised it (the "Incorrect syntax near" message) gets that far, I can't find any reference that mysql has a contains function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are referring to full-text indexing and the `CONTAINS` function is used in T-SQL/SQL Server I'm guessing you might not be using MySQL but rather MS SQL and if so the query should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Lotto 
WHERE CONTAINS (LotteryChoices, 'Markley OR Lindley OR Tagert OR Green OR Goodwin OR Wilson OR Greene OR Barnard OR Opa OR Taylor'
```

That is, with the `OR` as part of the contains_search_condition as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx).

(If you are indeed using MySQL I'll remove my answer)

Comment: I am using MS SQL, sorry I forgot to mention that since it effects syntax. Good catch and thank you, that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LIKE` keyword, along with percent signs in the string.

```
select * from Lotto where (LotteryChoices like '%Markley%') or (LotteryChoiceslike '%Lindley%') and so on
```

its an easy way to use `LIKE` instead of `CONTAINS`.

Answer (score 0):

Use in

```
SELECT *
FROM Lotto
WHERE LotteryChoices IN('Markley','Lindley','Tagert','Green','Goodwin','Wilson','Greene','Barnard','Opa','Taylor')
```

Comment: Actually, is LotteryChoices more than just the name?